# How to make an external class objects (which are instantiate outside the class) accessible to any other classes in php

Tags: php, class, object, global-variables, instantiation

```
# database.php #
class Database
{
    public function connect(){ //code }
    public function select(){ //code }
    public function insert(){ //code }
    public function update(){ //code }
    public function delete(){ //code }
}

# encryption.php #
class Crypt
{
    public function encrypt(){ //code }
    public function decrypt(){ //code }
}

# notify.php #
class notify
{
    public function setNotify(){ //code }
    public function getNotify(){ //code }
}

# index.php #
include ('database.php');
include ('encryption.php');
include ('notify.php');
$db = new Database();
$crypt = new Crypt();
$notify = new notify();

class one
{
    function execute()
    {
        $db->select(); // $db is the external object of Database class (database.php)
        $notify->setNotify(); // $notify is the external object of Notify class (notify.php)
    }
    function store()
    {
        $db->insert(); // $db is the external object of Database class (database.php)
        $notify->setNotify(); // $notify is the external object of Notify class (notify.php)
    }

}

class two
{
    function cypher()
    {
        $crypt->encrypt(); // $crypt is the external object of Crypt class (crypt.php)
        $db->update(); // $db is the external object of Database class (database.php)
        $notify->setNotify(); // $notify is the external object of Notify class (notify.php)
    }

}

$one = new one();
$two = new two();
$one->execute();
$two->cypher();
$one->store();
```

There are 4 files, database.php, encryption.php, notify.php and index.php. The first 3 files are instantiated only once. They can be called in any file or class. How to call or access the objects of a class which are instantiated outside the class. For example:

```
$db = new Database();
$crypt = new Crypt();
$notify = new notify();
```

are the objects with are instantiated outside the class one and class two in index.php. How to access the objects `$db`, `$crypt` and `$notify` within the `class one {}` and `class two {}`? How to make those objects act like a global object?

Comment: This can be done via Dependency Injection. You can find a few examples [here](http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Be careful when introducing global state in your software because it can cause problems later on.

One possible solution to your specific problem:

```
class SingletonManager
{

/**
 * Stores singleton instances
 * @var array
 */
protected static $_instances = array();

/**
 * Used to instantiate singletons
 * @param callable $factoryMethod
 * @return object of type returned by $factoryMethod or null
 */
public static function factory(callable $factoryMethod)
{
    /**
     * @var object
     */
    $singleton = $factoryMethod();
    // save reference to created object
    self::$_instances[get_class($singleton)] = $singleton;
    // return object
    return $singleton;
}

/**
 * Returns singleton object
 * @param string $className
 * @return object|null
 */
public static function instance($className)
{
    // check if there is an instance of $className
    if (isset(self::$_instances[$className])) {
        return self::$_instances[$className];
    }

    return null;
}

}
// end class definition

// mock database class
class Database
{
    public $username = '';
}

// create database object for the first time
SingletonManager::factory(function(){
    $database = new Database();
    $database->username = "username";
    return $database;
});

// access database object later from anywhere
$databaseObject = SingletonManager::instance("Database");
print_r($databaseObject);
```

Note that 'callable' type hinting is available in php5.4+